# How to Get URL when application launch via facebook?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, deep-linking

I am sharing a facebook link using this method `presentShareDialogWithLink` in my application. When user tap on the post in facebook application then this opens my application automatically, at that time i want to get the url on what user tap in facebook application. How do i get that url and where i'll get that url?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URL by method handleOpenURL in AppDelegate

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {

   /* Do something with the url */
}
```

Comment: thanks but may i parse this url? because it have many things in it like FBID authorize and access token and then url. how can i parse only my url?

Comment: Use your logic to parse the url. Take a look at this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString)

Answer (score 0):

If you've set up a handler during the present* call, something like:

```
[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:url
                              handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Success!");
    }
 }];
```

Then in your AppDelegate, override the application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {

    BOOL urlWasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                  fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call) {
                                      NSLog(@"Unhandled deep link: %@", url);
                                  }];

    return urlWasHandled;
}
```

Then your handler should get a callback.

For more info, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share-dialog/, in particular, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share-dialog/#handling-responses